# total variation of piecewise constant average function

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Let $u$ be a function defined on the interval $[0,1]$. Then, partition the unit interval into subintervals of length $1/h $ and consider "discrete" piecewise constant function $\bar u$ on $[0,1]$ defined as the average on each subinterval.

Then, how does one show that the total variation of $\bar u$ is less than or equal to $u$?